# Accepted way of checking for SharePoint CSOM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

What I'm trying to do is build a dual purpose JavaScript that might run inside or outside of SharePoint, so I need something like this:

```
if(SharePoint CSOM Exists)
{
//Do a bunch of stuff involving the SharePoint CSOM as well
}
else
{
//We can run outside of SharePoint as well
}
```

Is there a standard for doing this?  My hunch says it's just if(SP){} but wanted to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the style of script you're writing is probably fairly unique in the wild (how do you handle authentication if you're in the non-SP case and you use something like a REST request, for instance?) so you may not find a genuine 'standard' for doing this --  but checking for the SP object being initialized would be sufficient in most cases.

If you wanted to be a bit more specific, I would actually check for `SP` and `SP.ClientContext` since practically everything in the Javascript Client Object Model relies on the ClientContext.

Comment: The JavaScript in question does not really need authentication.  Most of the SharePoint stuff is adapting styling and using SharePoint modals.